# What's the difference between the variable name of an array and the address of that array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-address

In C++, the following code will compile:

```
int a[5];
int (*b)[5] = &a;
```

while this won't:

```
int a[5];
int (*b)[5] = a;
```

When compiling the second one, g++ gives me an error, saying "cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[5]' in initialization".

However, I thought that `a` and `&a` are just the same because

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

and

```
std::cout << &a << std::endl;
```

produce the same result.

Apparently, there is a difference between `a`, which is the **name of the array variable**, and `&a`, which is the **address of that array**. But what exactly is the difference?

Comment: That's like asking why `i` and `&i` for some `int i;` is not the same. What exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: @BaummitAugen to be fair, `cout << i` can have different output than `cout << &i`, while `cout << a` is always same as `cout &a` (when a is an array and i is an integer).

Comment: @user2079303 Not if `a` is `char[]`, but that's probably the only exception. (Also, note that my first comment is older than the clarifying edit.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sorry for not commenting your comment before that edit. But why can't a be `char[]`?

Comment: It does not print the same output if `a` is `char[]` because of the `operator<<` overload for `char*`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/x6DadFBlvBpLViYJ (Also not commenting is completely fine, no need to clutter up the comment section. Just editing to clarify was the right thing to do.)

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ an array within an expression decays to a pointer to it's first element. So, in you seconds example, the left is initialized with a int* to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Their values (addresses they are pointing to) are equal, but their types differ:

- (in that context) `a` is (`int [5]` decayed to) `int *`.
- `&a` is `int (*)[5]`

---

If you declare `int x;`, you could observe the same difference (in type but not in value) between, for example, `&x` and `(char *)&x`.